# using notion API and it runs well on local but throw 403 error after deployed through Vercel

Tags: next.js, notion-api

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPluw.png)I'm using Notion Api for showing images and it runs well on local but throw 403 error after deployed through Vercel.
Any help please.

I tried deploy again and it worked (didn't throw any error) yesterday, but when I checked it today it was throwing same error again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.